# SSIS FTP Task execution hangs until time out and stops without error and does not transfer the file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ftp

I have installed SQL Server 2012 and Sql Server Data Tool.
I created a package with FTP Task to extract a file from my site to a folder in my station.
After creating a connection to my site and testing connection, creating variable to define the local path, and filling the data in the FTP Task Editor I confirm with Build and get Build Succeeded, and click for execution. 
It Takes along time - I believe up to timeout and gives me "Package Execution Completed...". I The FTP Task object the red error sign and the file was not up loaded.

Here is the FTP Task Editor
[image: FTP Task Editor]

And the Remote Variable
[image: RemoteVariable]

Comment: Some ways to debug:  (1) Can you see the connection being made from the FTP site? (2) Can you write to your local path? (3) You have selected "Receive Files" - yet you say the file was not uploaded - do you mean to upload files (Send) from the local machine?

Comment: 1 when I test the connection using the FTP Connection manage I get OK.

Comment: 1 when I test the connection using the FTP Connection manage I get OK.
this its the only way I know how to check.it I don't Know how to create the addrses inside the site through browse, I just right the value of the variavle. I can write the local address, and I meant Send to local.
How can I check if the FTP is working correctly in my computer??